# AS2 (Applicability Statement 2) XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml, encryption, edi

Can you suggest me something different from as2secure.com because it doesn't work. I want to be free and to work with PHP. Or at least can you explain me the whole process to implement it! I should have both client and server side. As I know the flow is like this:
Client ->message->encrypt->sign->send
server->receive->check sign->decrypt->do some stuff->return response to client
Can you explain me a little also all this stuff with encryption what keys should use both/client server and so on. 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860218/handling-appliciability-statement-2-as2-requests).  If you have run into the MD5 "problem", then AS2 Secure will not work.  Usually partners will send self-signed user certificates (in the form of a .cer, .der file) to each other, which they will import into a certificate store, and get assigned to a partner connection.

There is a complete [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4130.txt) that you need to read that defines the standard.

Why do you want to write this yourself?  You have to figure out the mailboxing / message routing, if the request / response is synchronous or asynchronous, reading in and creating the correct MIME headers for the document with the correct AS2-To Identifiers.  You have to figure out which hashing algorithms your trading partner wants you to use. You are reinventing a decade old wheel and wasting a ton of time and money by wanting to write it yourself (unless you are building a commercial product, in which case you are entering a market with hundreds of competitors).  Please take a look at my other answer to this similar question.

Comment: I've saw this post you showed me.But I cannot make AS2 secure working.I need 100% php free solution which obviously is only this.That's why i'm asking. I need this things:
hash encryption -SHA1 
encryption algorithm -triple des
Request Method -Asynchronous
i should sign both messages and receipts. I cannot do run AS2 secure working with this parameters.If you help me with it or at least explain me the whole process.
thanks :)

Comment: What doesn't work about AS2 secure?  Have you contacted them? What was your setup like?  You seem to have the process down, but again, the RFC should put you in the right direction, as that is the standard.